# Angular $scope.$apply on asynchronous process

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, scope

I'm trying to update scope's objects. The new data in coming from an asynchronous process, in this case data from facebook.

How can i apply the changes to the html?

```
    var getCampaignStatistics = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.campaigns.length; i++) {

            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.campaigns[i].campaignStatistics = new CampaignStatistics(delegate);
                $scope.campaigns[i].campaignStatistics.startProcess();
            });
        }
    };


    var delegate = function () {

    };
```

so i have a delegate function that is being call once each of the statistic processes has finished. 
I tried also to apply the process, but I knew it wouldn't help because of the asynchronous request to facebook

I should  add the process  but it a long process with a lot of calculating.
Basically, it just set a statistics object inside the campaignStatistics. In the statistics objects there is params such as - pictures count etc...
In the end of the process, it calls the delegate function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your delegate/callback is supposed to do, but I assume that it takes parameters as well.  I'd try running the $apply in there, because the Facebook API will be making a call to it once the process finishes.  Angular won't know about that, because that process runs outside of its scope.

So you have to move your call to $apply to the delegate to make sure it is aware of the update whenever the Facebook API is ready to make use of your callback.

```
var getCampaignStatistics = function () {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.campaigns.length; i++) {
        $scope.campaigns[i].campaignStatistics = new CampaignStatistics(delegate);
        $scope.campaigns[i].campaignStatistics.startProcess();
    }
};


var delegate = function (param) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        //your logic here
        $scope.sompeProperty = param;
    });
};
```

Comment: The delegate function just being called once the process is finished and all the statistics in the campaigns statistics were calculated.

I have an ng-repeat in my code. So every time a statistics process is being finished i want to update the related campaign